# How to create a immediately-completed client response?

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to stub-out a JAX-RS client request. Instead of making an HTTP call, I want to return an immediately-completed client `Response`. I tried invoking `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok().build()`, unfortunately when the application invokes `Response.getEntity()` later on it gets this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not supported on an outbound message.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(OutboundJaxrsResponse.java:144
```

I dug into Jersey's source-code but couldn't figure out a way to do this. **How can one translate a server-side `Response` to a client-side `Response` in Jersey (or more generally JAX-RS)?**

### Use-case

I want to stub-out the HTTP call in a development environment (not a unit test) in order to prove that the network call is responsible for a performance problem I am seeing. I tried using a profiler to do this, but the call is asynchronous with 500+ threads and some network calls return fast (~100ms) while others return much slower (~1.5 seconds). Profilers do not follow asynchronous workflows well, and even if they did they only display the average time consumed across all invocations. I need to see the timing for each individual call. Stubbing-out the network call allows me to test whether the server is returning calls with such a large delta (100ms to 1.5 seconds) or whether the surrounding code is responsible.

Comment: How about just extending `Response`? The `InboundJaxrsResponse` which is Jersey's extension of `Response` is package private so you can't create it.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha It looks like a lot of work, but I agree this will probably work. Thanks for the idea!